# Is there an additional security layer on sessions on parse.com?

Tags: session, parse-platform, cloud

I am trying to limit the number of logins from all devices to 1.
My approach is to call a cloud function on login to retrieve the number
of active sessions for this user and return the result.
If the result is greater than one then prompt the user to either

- logout at the other device(s) or
- cancel login

The problem is that the cloud function always returns an empty object.

Note: it doesn't matter if the "equalTo" line is enabled or not, the result is always empty. If I test the code with another class it works.

```
Parse.Cloud.define("findSessions", function(request, response) {
  Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();

  var SessionClass = Parse.Object.extend("Session");
  var query = new Parse.Query(SessionClass);
  query.equalTo("user", request.user);

  query.find({
      success: function(results) {
          response.success({"count": results.length})
      },
      error: function(error) {
          response.error(error)
      }
  });
});
```

Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

And of course 10 minutes after posting my question I found the solution (after spending hours before with no success).

The trick is Session is it's own class. The moment I replace

```
var query = new Parse.Query(SessionClass);
```

with

```
Parse.Query(Parse.Session);
```

everything works.

Another nice trick: by removing the line

```
Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
```

I already get only the sessions I have access too. No need for filters.

Hope that helps someone with a similar problem.